# How to use powershell to deploy model into Analysis services without configure it to be http?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-analysis-services

Hi I have been trying to deploy model to analysis service by using XMLA script. I used deployment wizard and it worked fine. However when I tried to use command Invoke-ASCmd to deploy model to my analysis server. It got a error of targetinovation which I figured out to be my credential argument error.

The command I used:

```
$user = "myemail@outlook.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $user, $PWord
Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile AW.XMLA -Server asazure://southeastasia.asazure.windows.net/azurejenkins -Credential $Credential
```

But when I not use the -Credential argument it prompt the window email login which work fine. How do I use this command without prompting the user to enter email and password?

Comment: Try creating the Credential-Object like this `$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$user", $PWord)`

Comment: Did that and it's still can't deploy. Is there any another way? @Paxz

Comment: Maybe try creating Credentials via `Get-Credentials`, just to check if the problem is the credentials-object.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem.

I need to create webapp/api in active directory of azure. Copy its application id, tenant id and authentication key which you need to go to keys section in your app.

Go to SQL management server program which connected to your analysis server. Go to security and add app:@ in manual entry (in case you don't see your app in the list).

Then use the same command I used in the question but change some components. Change user email to your app id and password to your authentication key. Add tenant id.

```
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -Credential $Credential -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -RolloutEnvironment "xxxxxx.asazure.windows.net"
Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile xx.XMLA -Server asazure://southeastasia.asazure.windows.net/xxxxxx -Credential $Credential
```

Hope this script help someone who has the same problem as mine.

Comment: Did it work? I get  unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type